# Not showing any driver for Nvidia gf117m graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04

After upgrading to 22.04 from 20.04 in the Software and Updates > Additional Drivers
it says "No additional drivers available".

here is the `lspci` results

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
09:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
0a:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
0a:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
```

Comment: on the third to last line of the `lspci` output you posted it shows `3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M`  -- Is there some reason to believe that the hardware is not working properly?  Are you experiencing any problems?

Comment: no, just the drivers are not showing in the Additional Drivers section.

Comment: How have you come to the conclusion that there is a problem?

Comment: If the driver for dedicated graphics isn't showing then it should mean that it isn't working, right?
I'm new to this so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The driver *is* showing. It's in the output of `lspci`. There aren't any *additional drivers*.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that, even though both GPUs show up in `lspci` and the NVidia is using the Nouveau driver, there is no option to switch to the NVidia proprietary driver, which is kind of important, because without it the GPU isn't switched on demand and we are left with the Intel graphics at all times.

I was able to solve the problem on my system by manually installing the `nvidia-390` drivers and the Prime applet via APT.

Answer (score 0):

> No additional drivers available

Your system is using a driver for your intel internal GPU and your nVidia graphics card. The system picks the correct open source version during install. If you pick "install additional drivers" during an install you get a couple more. Not sure how an upgrade does it but since all third party drivers normally are removed/disabled to not have the upgrade error out on those it would seem reasonable to assume this also is done for the third party nVidia driver making it fall back to the open source "nouveau".

"additional drivers" would mean you have different versions to install.  If there are none in the system you get nothing there.

---

We have a feature called `ubuntu-drivers`

This will show all available drivers:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo ubuntu-drivers list
```

It will show a list like this if there are any extra drivers available in the system:

```
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : {model}
... 
driver   : nvidia-driver-{nnn} - distro non-free {recommended}
driver   : nvidia-driver-{nnn}-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

The {nnn} shows the different versions (440, 455, 510) ; 1 will have recommended and is the one the system believes is the best one.

---

In case you need to reset to the recommended version you can do:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

---

I would advice against doing the remainder of this if you system is working properly and the slight slower speed of the open source version is not an issue (the only benefit for extra speed would be gaming). If you want to use an nVidia 3rd party driver or want to test different drivers keep going.

This command shows info specifically related to your display:

```
sudo lshw -C display
```

To add more options to the list `ubuntu-drivers` shows you can add nVidia drivers using the `graphics-drivers` PPA with (if you find any other PPA change the second command to that):

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa -y
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers list
```

If the list includes `nvidia-driver-515` (that is currently the highest version) you can install that one with

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515
```

A lower number should mean less features and less efficient. It is not guarenteed that a newer version is better for you so use

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

to revert to the recommended if needed. These commands do not require an active desktop and can also be used from grub command, or a terminal session.